AOP: aspect doesn't handle methods that called inside class
I have an interface:
public interface InputFld {

    void setText(String text);
    Locator getInputLocator();

}

And aspect for this interface:
@Before("execution(* com.my.project.elements.interfaces.InputFld.*(..))")
public void logBeforeMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint) {log.info(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());}

The issue is that when I call my methods from another component all works well:
@Component
class MyPage{
public void method(){
    loginPage.email().getInputLocator();
    loginPage.email().setText("TEXT");
}
}

But when I call in the way I need: (the getInputLocator() called from the implementation class):
class MyInput implements InputFld{
public void setText(String text){
    getInputLocator().fill(text);
}
}

aspect doesn't handle getInputLocator() method.

Am I able to handle such methods using AOP? (methods that are calling inside the class but not outer)

InputFld is not a Spring bean. It only works on Spring managed beans

@NicoVanBelle I added such objects through AspectJProxyFactory

When you are calling a method intercepted by AOP you are not calling the method of the actual class you declared, you are instead calling it on proxy class generated by CGLIB or JDK Dynamic Proxy instead.
Since Spring is an IoC (Inversion of Control) framework it can take over the managing of dependencies, meaning that when using spring you need only to worry about what kind of dependency you need, Spring handles finding a suitable implementation, and in this case Spring finds you a proxy to achieve AOP.
When you call the method from the class itself the method has code in which it directly specifies to itself: in this way Spring is not able to inject its proxy.
Spring "adds code" to your method to call the AOP logic before the execution in the case of before, but when your code contains "this" (even tho it's ommitted) you are referring specifically to your class, thus Spring has no way of altering the logic.
Instead when you call from Component with @Autowired dependency (Or however injected) a proxy can be called with no problem.
You can try printing the current class in a line of log to see that it's not actually the class you have declared but a proxy.
This question has the answers to how to solve your problem:
How to intercept each method call within given method using Spring AOP or AspectJ
